# Toggle UIViews Class on Tap

Tags: swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have 5 different `UIViews` in a `View Controller`, and I want to highlight only the last one that was tapped, by changing its border color.

I made a `Custom Highlighting Class` that encapsulates the desired effect in terms of design, and gave each UIView a `UITapGestureRecognizer` with its `#selector(toggleFunction)`.These 5 `UIViews` already have a class assigned to them, so basically I need to change the `Original Class` to the `Custom Class`, or just turn it on/off as needed.

My question is how can I toggle this Custom Class on and off as I tap between the 5 `UIViews`?

Comment: you will need to maintain currently selected UIView and upon changing that unselected last UIView and select new View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
extension UIView {

    func addBorder(_ add:Bool) {

        self.layer.borderColor = add ? UIColor.red.cgColor : UIColor.green.cgColor

        self.layer.borderWidth = add ? 5 : 0

    }
}
```

---

```
@objc func tapped(_ v:UITapGestureRecognizer) {

   let currentView = v.view!

   allViews.forEach {

      $0.addBorder($0 == currentView)
   }

}
```

---

suppose you have

```
var allViews = [UIView]()
```

Comment: But how do I access the toggle function inside a tap func?

Comment: It works amazing. It toggles the class on and off, however I am looking for the radio buttons effect. What should I change, constructing multiple toggle funcs for each view?

Comment: Works amazing. Thanks a lot. Sorry for not explaining clear enough right form the start.